# JavaScript Selenium button not clicked

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, click

I am trying to call a function to click a button in a selenium browser window.

```
function initSelenium() {
  let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();
  driver.get("https://www.ea.com/en-en/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/");

  driver.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Login']"))).click();
}
```

but for some reason nothing happens after the url is loaded.

I used selenium with python without issues.
but JS does not let me use this command to click a button.

anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is how you initialize the driver. Instead of `let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("firefox").build();` write `var driver = new webdriver.builder()` -- your code becomes

```
function initSelenium() {
  var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
     .forBrowser('firefox')
     .build();
  driver.get("https://www.ea.com/en-en/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/");

  driver.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Login']"))).click();
}
```